# Boostrap BS3 navbar Clic Dropdown-Submenu

Tags: jquery, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm using `Bootstrap BS3` in order to build my `Django website`. I'm writing `dropdown-submenu` which works on http://www.bootply.com/nZaxpxfiXz#

[image]

But When I applied the same thing to my project, I get :

[image]

I don't have the little arrow beside dropdown-menu title. So I can't navigate or even display submenus like :

- Accueil Fiches Individuelles
- Création Fiches Individuelles
- ...

This is my script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% load user_tags %}

    <title> DatasystemsEC - Accueil </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/Base.css' %}"/>
    </head>

    <!-- #################### -->
    <!-- Upper navigation bar -->
    <!-- #################### -->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.datasystems.fr/"> DatasystemsEC </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Home tab -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{% url "accueil" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Accueil </a></li> 

                <!-- Resume Tab with acts -->

                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Actes Etat Civil <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Fiches Individuelles </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Accueil Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Création Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Consultation Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Edition Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Suppression Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Actes de Naissance</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Accueil Actes de Naissance</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Création Actes de Naissance</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Consultation Actes de Naissance</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        {% block content %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% endblock content %}
</html>
```

I have a CSS file too :

```
/* ###################################################### */
/* CSS File about BirthCertificate application properties */
/* ###################################################### */

/* Define background color from upper navbar */
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #0083A2;
    }

/* DatasystemsEC tab */
.navbar-inverse .container-fluid .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color : white;
    }

/* Tab properties from navbar */
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    color:  white;
    }

.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
    color:  #454545;
    }

.active {
    background-color: #454545;
    }

/* Titles properties */
h1, h2, h4 {
    color: #0083A2;
    }

/* Define button properties */
.button {

    display: inline;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    }

/* Define form fields properties */
.form-fields {
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

.col-sm-6 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left : 10px;
    width: 30%;
    list-style: none;
    }

.col-sm-8 {
    list-style: initial;
    }

.col-sm-10 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left : 10px;
    width: 800%;
    list-style: none;
    }

/* Hoover button properties */
.button:hover {
    background-color: #0083A2;
    color: #454545;
    }

/* Hoover color dropdown menu */
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #0083A2;
    }

.logo {
    position : fixed ;
    top:0;
    left:100px;
}

@justify {
    text-align: justify;
}

.marginBottom-0 {margin-bottom:0;}

.dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:100%;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}
.dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{border-left-color:#555;}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left{float:none;}.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;}
```

Have you an idea ? I don't find a way to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title> DatasystemsEC - Accueil </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
    .marginBottom-0 {margin-bottom:0;}
    .dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
    .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:100%;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}
    .dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}
    .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{border-left-color:#555;}
    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left{float:none;}.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- #################### -->
    <!-- Upper navigation bar -->
    <!-- #################### -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.datasystems.fr/"> DatasystemsEC </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Home tab -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{% url "accueil" %}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Accueil </a></li> 

                <!-- Resume Tab with acts -->

                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Actes Etat Civil <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula">
                                    </span> Fiches Individuelles 
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Accueil Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Création Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Consultation Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Edition Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Suppression Fiches Individuelles</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Actes de Naissance</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Accueil Actes de Naissance</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Création Actes de Naissance</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Consultation Actes de Naissance</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <script>
            (function($){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                        event.stopPropagation(); 
                        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
                        $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>   
    </body>     
</html>
```

Does your Base.css and Base.js file contain the needed CSS and JS from http://www.bootply.com/nZaxpxfiXz# ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem come from the javascript and class name , let me explain my self :).

The `carret` you are talking about is not the one who will trigger the event to open the submenu and it should have been created by this line:

```css
.dropdown-submenu > a:after{
    display:block;
    content:" ";
    float:right;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color:#cccccc;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
```

Debug in your browser to understand why this rules is overrules by another one since you have this rules in the end of your file.

But beside the carret not showing up the menu should trigger but you say it is not so try this one:

Where you have `class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"`  i think it should be  `class="dropdown-submenu"` and the inner `<a>` should get `onclick="return false"` so try changing this and see what happen , i know on the site you show us it not like that but if your not using the exact same version as them.

`onclick="return false"` to not trigger the `<a>` event on submenu click, needed if not already done by another function of yours.

Comment: So `<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">` should be `<a onclick="return false" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">` ?

Comment: this `<li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"` become `<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" onclick="return false" class="dropdown-toggle"`

Comment: try to check if submenu is really activated on thoses element with : `$('#create-a-unique-id-for-a-submenu-to-debug').data('bs.submenu')` should display the submenupicker data object that you can explore and debug if not it mean it not event initialize on thoses element

Comment: Thank you, I'm really new with web developpement so it's realy hard for me. The commande `create-a-unique-..` Where I have to write it ?

Comment: inside the console browser type this but before take one `<li class="dropdown-submenu"` and adds a id just to select only this one. like `id="thesubmenu1"` then in the browser console you type in `$('#thesubmenu1').data('bs.submenu')` it should return a object if it return nothing/null or [] it is not initialise so try initialising first at that point i will say start from documentation not a example

Comment: Ok, I got this: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
 

...li class="dropdown-submenu"
id="thesubmenu1"
$('#thesubmenu1').data('bs.submenu'`

Comment: u should not have a error there , look carefully the command typed , another check can be to see if submenupicker exist inside jQuery with : in console type `$.fn.submenupicker` should return a function

Comment: The command : `$.fn.submenupicker` is returned by : `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

You are using that icon:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-baby-formula"></span> Fiches Individuelles </a>
```

Change *glyphicon-baby-formula* to the icon you want to use, maybe *glyphicon-triangle-right*

Comment: It's not the problem. I'm talking about arrow which let to navigate to submenu as the first picture

Comment: Using your html and css, I see the arrows. It is possible you have something overwriting your styles?

Comment: In my Django project (blue/white colors) you see submenus ? It's strange

Comment: I have built a project using your html and your css (the ones you have copied), and I can see the arrows, not the menus

Comment: So the problem still exists. I don't get submenus in my navbar with bootstrap. If I put bootstrap 2.3.2, it works, but I want a recent version (BS3 or BS4)

Comment: If I add the JS code from http://www.bootply.com/nZaxpxfiXz#, it works perfectly in my local project...